# Couldn't resolve host 'magento-community'?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

whenever I try to install a new magento extension through Magento Connnect I am getting this error message.

```
Couldn't resolve host 'magento-community'
```

I have tried with a lot of magento extensions like Easy Tab, Mygento JQuery Library and Powerful plugins, Cash On Delivery and So on. When I get the Key for any Particular extension I paste it in **"Paste extension key to install:"** field and press **Install** button ANd I get the above error. Is It a Bug In magento or Am I Doing anything wrong. Please Help ...?

Comment: Connect has been in a constant state of flux since the relaunch.  If you're having trouble installing extensions get in touch with the community manager: https://twitter.com/rondata

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using  http://www.magentocommerce.com/

Use http://connect20.magento-commerce.com/

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you are trying to install :
 **magento-community/Exclusiveconcepts_Conversionsondemand**

Then change the key to install to

**http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Exclusiveconcepts_Conversionsondemand**

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using Magento version 1.5+, select magento connect version 2.0 when installing an extension.
2. In the settings tab in magento connect screen, select "Http" option in "Magento Connect Channel Protocol" section